# Get user by meta data key and velue

Tags: php, functions, user-meta

I have create custom user meta, but it was array how i can call only one of them by key like I want to get only `course_id = 22` list.
Here this my user meta array

```
 [certifications] => Array
        (
            [0] => a:9:{s:9:"course_id";a:2:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:2:"19";}s:11:"course_name";a:2:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:18:"Advanced Freediver";}s:6:"course";a:2:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:2:"19";}s:4:"date";a:2:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:10:"05/03/2019";}s:10:"instructor";a:2:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:11:"Camila Amor";}s:6:"school";a:2:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:24:"Apnea Total Headquarters";}s:11:"pdf_card_id";a:2:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:2:"19";}s:7:"pdf_dip";a:2:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:2:"19";}s:11:"last_update";s:10:"21-03-2019";}
            [1] => a:9:{s:9:"course_id";a:2:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:2:"22";}s:11:"course_name";a:2:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:16:"Master Freediver";}s:6:"course";a:2:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:2:"22";}s:4:"date";a:2:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:10:"08/03/2019";}s:10:"instructor";a:2:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:14:"Andres Alegria";}s:6:"school";a:2:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:17:"Vertical Dreamers";}s:11:"pdf_card_id";a:2:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:2:"22";}s:7:"pdf_dip";a:2:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:2:"22";}s:11:"last_update";s:10:"21-03-2019";}
        )
```

Comment: how are you creating this meta? and why is it being stored as serialized data inside an array?

Comment: it is default array stored from wordpress.

Comment: please add the code you are using to create/store that meta and what you are using to pull it out in the current format

Comment: This how my stored function is for this meta group

$certification = array(
  'course_name' => $certificate_name,
  'course' => $certificate,
  'date' => $date,
  'instructor' => $certifying_instructor,
  'school' => $school,
  'last_update' => date('d-m-Y'),
 );

 add_user_meta( $user_ids, 'certifications',  $certification );

Comment: If you have to have them all stored in a single meta field ('certifications') then you're going to need to parse out the data in them and then pullout the array you want from there.  check out [`maybe_unserialize()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_unserialize/) for help getting that data into a readable format

Answer (score 0):

This how my stored data function is for this meta group and get data

**stored**

```
$certification = array(
        'course_id' => $certificate_id,
        'course' => $certificate,
        'date' => $date,
        'instructor' => $certifying_instructor,
        'school' => $school,
        'last_update' => date('d-m-Y'),
    );

    add_user_meta( $user_ids, 'certifications',  $certification );
```

**and this get data**

```
$users_detail = get_user_meta($user_id);
$certificates = $users_detail['certifications'];

$n_course_id = array();

foreach ($certificates as $value) {
   $course = unserialize($value);
   $course_id = $course['course_id'];

   foreach ($course_id as $courses) {
     array_push($n_course_id, $courses);
   }

}
```

by this function i can get all list but i want to get only one of them